# How do I retrieve the title of a term of a custom post type with custom taxonomies?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'movie' ));

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        ?>

        <div> 
        <?php $term = the_terms($movie->ID,'Genre'); ?>

        </div>


    <?php }


    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
else {
    // no posts found
}
?>
```

Comment: Please edit your question, explain your problem as specific as possible, format your code, but don't rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

It works the same way within any Loop for any post type and taxonomy, `get_the_ID()` retrieves the current post's ID. Taken from [the Codex basic example for `get_the_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/):

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'genre' );
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) { 
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo $term->name;
    }
}
```